# How to specify installation path before installing program with CMD in C#?

Tags: c#, cmd, mariadb, windows-installer

I have an app where I'm downloading MariaDB in specific path and after that I run the installer but I would like to change the path where MariaDB will be installed, this is the code I'm working with

```
private void InstalarMariaDB()
    {
        try
        {
            Process proceso = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = rutaDirectorio;
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C msiexec /i MariaDB.msi /passive";
            proceso.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proceso.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I need to do this in the arguments line I guess

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C msiexec /i MariaDB.msi /passive";
```

I tried this but didn't work because it says params are not valid for the list of msi installer
[Silent installation with target directory path as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767450/silent-installation-with-target-directory-path-as-parameter/50773797)

```
Arguments = "/s /v/qn /vINSTALLDIR=\"+targetDir+"\""
```

I hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: My first advice is not running `cmd.exe` to run `msiexec.exe`. This is absolutely not needed at all. Run directly `msiexec.exe` which is always located in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`. So get value of environment variable `SystemRoot`, concatenate it with `\System32\msiexec.exe` and then run this program from within C# coded application without `cmd.exe`. The Windows [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) should be taken into account on compiling the C# coded app as 32-bit executable, but executed should be ...

Comment: ... 64-bit `msiexec.exe` on 64-bit Windows while running 32-bit `msiexec.exe` on 32-bit Windows. The options supported by `msiexec.exe` itself are displayed in a GUI window opened on running `msiexec.exe /?`. All other options like an option for a silent installation or another option for an installation directory must be supported by the MSI file itself. So you need to get information about the supported options by `MariaDB.msi` from author of this Microsoft Installer package.

Comment: If you're able to get the MSI to launch but still not get it installed you should also have it log the install. You'll see under the /? switch that this is simply /L*V <pathToLog>.

Look at the MariaDB website to determine how to install it to a different location from the command line. As a last resort you can also use Orca to open the MariaDB.msi and set the InstallDir directly before installing.

Comment: @Mofi thank you for your comments I did that based on what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve my issue based on the comments I read on here

```
private void InstalarMariaDB()
    {
        try
        {
            // MSI path
            string rutaMSI = rutaDirectorio + "MariaDB.msi";
            // Installation path
            string rutaInstalacion = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PudveBD\";
            // Service name
            string servicio = "PudveBD";
            // Args
            string argumentos = string.Format("/qn /i \"{0}\" INSTALLDIR=\"{1}\" ALLUSERS=1 PORT=6666 SERVICENAME=\"{2}\"", rutaMSI, rutaInstalacion, servicio);

            Process proceso = new Process();
            proceso.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            proceso.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentos;
            proceso.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            proceso.Start();
            proceso.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```